# cutting a field to length with awk/sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a rather large bunch of files that contains several fields pipe-delimited.

> 5595340959340|1|MXPYAQWE|870569689456954654|0|0|20181018224126|**1212121212121212121212121212**|2|0|1000|70|33107||1|Event
>       5595340959340|1|MXPYAQWE|870569689456954654|0|0|20181018224126|**2323232323232323232323232323**|2|0|1000|70|33107||1|Event
>       5595340959340|1|MXPYAQWE|870569689456954654|0|0|20181018224126|**3434343434343434343434343434**|2|0|1000|70|33107||1|Event
>       5595340959340|1|MXPYAQWE|870569689456954654|0|0|20181018224126|**4545454545454545454545454545**|2|0|1000|70|33107||1|Event
>       5595340959340|1|MXPYAQWE|870569689456954654|0|0|20181018224126|**5656565656565656565656565656**|2|0|1000|70|33107||1|Event

Notice the eighth field. It currently has 29 characters and I'm supposed to trim it so it has only five characters left.

The only (convoluted) solution I've come up with is this:

**Isolate the fields I want to trim:**

```
awk -F "|" '{print $8}' > Original_Fields
```

**Trim the fields**

```
cp Original_Fields Temp
more Temp | cut -c -5 > Trimmed_Fields
```

**Create a susbtitution script with sed**

```
grep -rh -f <file_with_matching_strings> /path/to/files > Original_Strings
vi Original_Strings
:%s/^/grep -rl "/g
:%s/$/" \/path\/to\/file | xargs sed -i 's\//g
:wq!
```

And then edit the Original_Fields and Trimmed_Fields files, so I end up with

```
grep -rl /path/to/file | xargs sed -i 's/Original_Field/Trimmed_Field/g'
```

This works, but I strongly suspect there must be a quicker way to accomplish this with AWK and SED, so I can do all of this in just one step.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can trim and rebuild each line with AWK:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { $8 = substr($8, 1, 5); print }'
```

This sets the input and output separators to “|”, and for each line of input, trims the eighth field to five characters at most, and prints all the fields (including the updated field).

Answer (score 2):

Since your file is fixed width — or at least it seems — you can do it counting columns to keep and discard in sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.{68}).{23}(.*)/\1\2/' yourfile
```